# Generate Histogram on data as like mysql

Tags: mysql, hadoop, histogram

I have tables with average of 5 million records in mysql. For data analytics purpose, I would like to generate histogram on data for some columns as like MYSQL histograms. Only records matching some criteria must me included in histogram generation. Any suggestions on generating and maintaining histograms?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: As of now a cron job with query the table with a simple group by (column that needs a histogram). Due to the large size the query takes more time to complete.

Comment: If you can share some query with data and expected output that would be better.

Comment: Hi, We tried using Hadoop for storing the data and running MapReduce jobs to compute the histogram. Our data is like a simple table and we would like to find the frequency distribution of values in each column. But the drawback is we were not able to keep the data in sync with mysql for every write queries. Syncing all the data causes increase in mysql I/O. Hadoop did not suit our need of dynamic data updation